# How to store app tokens and secrets for ionic apps

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I'm using adjust and firebase in my ionic app but the app secrets for these integrations and others all show up in my app's js code if I extract the APK/IPA.

How do I keep credentials secure and package them with the app's APK/IPA for such hybrid apps?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and it's good that you are asking it :)

For the Firebase settings, they are secret, but not secret-secret. They are just a starting point. Nothing can be done with those unless the user also logs in with their password which is hashed using the secret key and then sent over.

This proves that the person knows enough to identify themselves as a user.

Then on the server side, you have your rules that say "for the person that has identified themselves as user X they have permission to do Y"

If somebody has got your password then you are exposed just the same as you are always exposed.

You can also restrict your Firebase account by apps package id, hostname, IP address, in the Google Cloud admin panels.

As for your other things, like Adjust, they have their own solutions along the same lines. Either the API key is just enough for you to read the information, or if its a powerful level of access then normally there is some kind of authentication/account linking process so you can prove yourself to the other API.

If not, then you cannot just put it out there, you need to create your own proxy. Firebase supports cloud functions (aka serverless) so you can run snippets of code which are only accessible by users that have logged in, and then return that information back to the client as a proxy.